# Exclude headers for ItemStyle- Width for gridview?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, header, coding-style

I´m trying to play around ItemStyle- Width and but this only works if  i use Attribites.Add("Style"...) in my page load.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {

...

        }

        gwActivity.Attributes.Add("style", "word-break:break-all;word-wrap:break-word");


    }
```

However this is not a problem. My issue is that the column headers are affected in the ItemStyle-Width:... and i do NOT want that to be the case. Can i only play around with the rows and not the headers?

```
<%--************************ Gridview section ************************--%>
        <asp:GridView ID="gwActivity" runat="server"  AutoGenerateColumns="False" OnRowCommand="gwActivity_RowCommand" CssClass="gwActivity"  >
            <Columns>

                <asp:BoundField DataField="ActivityID" HeaderText="ActivitID"></asp:BoundField>

            </Columns>

            <HeaderStyle BackColor="#E6E6E6" Font-Bold="false" Font-Names="Arial" ForeColor="#000000"  />
            <%-- <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="#E6E6E6" /> --%>
        </asp:GridView>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this..

```
    <asp:GridView ID="gwActivity" runat="server"  
 AutoGenerateColumns="False" OnRowCommand="gwActivity_RowCommand" 
  CssClass="gwActivity"  >
 <HeaderStyle BackColor="#E6E6E6" Font-Bold="false" ForeColor="#000000" Font-Names="Arial  />
        <Columns>

            <asp:BoundField DataField="ActivityID" HeaderText="ActivitID"></asp:BoundField>

<asp:BoundField DataField="ActivityID" HeaderText="ActivitID" HeaderStyle-Font-Bold="false"
                                HeaderStyle-Font-Size="12px" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" ItemStyle-Width="25">
                               <HeaderStyle Font-Bold="False" Font-Size="12px" />
                                <ItemStyle Font-Size="12px" HorizontalAlign="Left" Width="200px" /> //set width you want..
                            </asp:BoundField>

        </Columns>

    </asp:GridView>
```